# is it possible to combine sapply with one constraint in R?

Tags: r

I'm fitting different models and then I would like to compute the VIF from package car. The VIF requires more than one regressor in the formula so returns an error. The idea is that check whether there is more than one regressor before running the function. Alternatively, I can try to sort the models by number of regressors so the VIF function is called only from the ith position on.

My code is:

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
ot=rnorm(length(trt))
ot2=rnorm(length(trt))
DF=as.data.frame(cbind(ot,ot2,ctl,trt))
y=colnames(DF[1])
x = colnames(DF)
x = x[! x %in% y]
n = length(x)

id = unlist(
  lapply(1:n,
         function(i)combn(1:n,i,simplify=F)
  )
  ,recursive=F)

models = sapply(id,function(i)
  paste(y,paste(x[i],collapse="+"), sep="~")
)

allModelsResults=lapply(models, function(i) 
  lm(as.formula(i), data=DF))

library(car)
vif.r=sapply(allModelsResults,vif)
```

Comment: @flodel I'm sorry is from library(car)

Comment: @user1228124 So why don't you edit that into the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
sapply(allModelsResults,
       function(mod) if (length(labels(terms(mod))) < 2) NA else vif(mod))

# [[1]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] NA
# 
# [[4]]
#      ot2      ctl 
# 1.157776 1.157776 
# 
# [[5]]
#      ot2      trt 
# 1.439415 1.439415 
# 
# [[6]]
#      ctl      trt 
# 1.264959 1.264959 
# 
# [[7]]
#     ot2     ctl     trt 
# 1.47575 1.29689 1.61237
```

Note that `length(labels(terms(mod))) < 2` is what `vif` is using as its criterion, see `getAnywhere(vif.lm)`.